# Need help batch renaming video files in a specific format

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, file-rename

I am working on renaming files that come from digital camera video recordings.
They output files in a generic incremental filename of which I do not need any information from. My folder structure is: `x:\processing\01020304\VIDEO\0001.avi`.

The filename I am trying to achieve would be for this example:

> 01-02-20121227-07h30m00s-03-04.avi

In this example, `01-02` is the first 4 numbers of the `01020304` folder. `20121227` is the date the video was created, with `07h30m00s` as the ending time of the video, which is usually reported by the "last modified time". finally the `03-04` is the second half of the folder name used previously.

I'm a complete novice to writing batch files like this, but was unable to find any other examples similar enough to get myself started, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit:
so far I've got:

```
    @echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Setup
set "xPath=c:\processing\01010101\VIDEO"
set "xFolder="
set "xDateCreated="

:: Parse Folder Name
for /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%A in ("%xPath%") do set "xFolder=%%A"

:: Loop through Videos
pushd %xPath%
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,*" %%A in ('dir *.avi /T:W /4') do if exist "%%~fE" (
    set "xDateCreated=%%~A %%~B %%~C"
    echo %xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateCreated:~6,4!!xDateCreated:~0,2!!

xDateCreated:~3,2!-!xDateCreated:~11,2!h-!xDateCreated:~14,2!m-00s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%

xFolder:~6,2%%%~xE
)
popd

endlocal
pause
```

we're almost there, just missing the seconds, and if possible id like to change it so i do not have to supply the directory, but rather run it from the processing folder and check all 01010101, 02010101, etc directories..

Comment: Thanks for the formatting oldskool, it definitely reads a lot better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Create Empty Folder
rd /Q "%Temp%\Temp" 2>nul & mkdir "%Temp%\Temp"

:: Loop through Folders
pushd "xPath=x:\processing"
for /d %%D in (*) do call :Process "%%~fD"
popd
goto End


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:Process <Parent>
:: Folder Name
set "xFolder=%~nx1"

:: Set Sub Folder
if not exist "%~1\VIDEO\" goto :eof
pushd "%~1\VIDEO"

:: Loop through Videos
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir *.avi /b') do if exist "%%~fA" (
    set "xDateWritten=%%~tA"
    set "xDateGMT=0000/00/00 00:00:00"
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%X in ('robocopy . "%Temp%\Temp" "%%~nxA" /TS /FP /NS /NC /NP /NJH /NJS /NDL /L') do set "xDateGMT=%%X %%Y"
    rem Format = FF-FF-YYYYMMDD-HHh-MMm-SSs-FF-FF.ext
    echo %xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateWritten:~6,4!!xDateWritten:~0,2!!xDateWritten:~3,2!-!xDateWritten:~11,2!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xA
)
popd
goto :eof


:End
endlocal
pause
```

Since you changed the `T:C` to `T:W` I adjusted the script to just use the Last Written Date and I added the folder recursion.

When ready replace the `echo` line with this:

```
ren "%%~fA" "%xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateWritten:~6,4!!xDateWritten:~0,2!!xDateWritten:~3,2!-!xDateWritten:~11,2!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xA"
```

---

**Original & Edits**

Well to keep the script simple I am basing the formatting strictly off the folders structure you posted. This is just a skeleton script to get you started.  It works, but does not get the length of the video.  The length can be calculated based on the information already retrieved, but I did not feel like doing date math right now. :)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Setup
rd /Q "%Temp%\Temp" & mkdir "%Temp%\Temp" 2>nul
set "xPath=x:\processing\01020304\VIDEO"
set "xFolder="

:: Parse Folder Name
for /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%A in ("%xPath%") do set "xFolder=%%A"

:: Loop through Videos
pushd %xPath%
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,*" %%A in ('dir *.avi /T:C /4') do if exist "%%~fE" (
    set "xDateWritten=%%~tE"
    set "xDateCreated=%%~A %%~B %%~C"
    set "xDateGMT=0000000000000000000"
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %%X in ('robocopy . "%Temp%\Temp" "%%~E" /TS /FP /NS /NC /NP /NJH /NJS /NDL /L') do set "xDateGMT=%%X %%Y"
    echo %xFolder:~0,2%-%xFolder:~2,2%-!xDateCreated:~6,4!!xDateCreated:~0,2!!xDateCreated:~3,2!-!xDateWritten:~11,2!h-!xDateWritten:~14,2!m-!xDateGMT:~17,2!s-%xFolder:~4,2%-%xFolder:~6,2%%%~xE
)
popd

endlocal
pause
```

Unfortunately, the `t` option and `dir` command do not provide the date resolution needed for seconds.  To obtain the full last modified time stamp of the file you can use either the `forfiles` or `robocopy` commands.

```
rd /Q "%Temp%\Temp" 2>nul & mkdir "%Temp%\Temp" && robocopy . "%Temp%\Temp" *.avi /TS /FP /NS /NC /NP /NJH /NJS /NDL /L
```

**NOTE:** RoboCopy returns the time stamp of the file in GMT+0!  It does not return the time stamp based upon the user's timezone settings. To determine which timezone you are, use `tzutil /g`.

See [`RoboCopy /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (Vista+ or XP Resource Kit)

```
forfiles /M *.avi /C "cmd /c echo @ftime"
```

See [`ForFile /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (Vista+)

**Edit:**

I updated the code to include the last written hour and minute into the file name.  All that needs to be done is to add the `rename` command in the loop.  To obtain the seconds for the time stamp from the files, either the `robocopy` or `forfiles` commands will have to be used.

**Edit 2:**
Added note about RoboCopy and the GMT+0 file time stamp and updated code to work with this limitation.  Added the `rd` and `mkdir` to ensure that we have an empty folder, Added the `for` parse for the `robocopy` file timestamp, and added the `xDateGMT` variable.  This should fully work now, if I have time later, I will clean it up a little more.

**Edit 3:**

Reformatted the answer to make it cleaner. See above Update section.

Comment: neither forfiles or robocopy seem to work for me, i am on XP btw. also i do not need the actual length of the file, just its creation date.

Comment: @user1932480 I guess I should have added the disclaimer, but RoboCopy and ForFiles are only distributed on Windows Vista and newer versions of Windows.  RoboCopy can be added to XP through this Windows Resource Pack: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657

Comment: ok i got the resource pack installed, and robocopy seems to be working, except it returns a timestamp of "13:30:10" when it should be returning 7:30:xx. thoughts?

Comment: and after some more searching i see robocopy reports the timestamp in GMT+0 timezone... so i dont know if its going to output the correct values or not here.

Comment: @user1932480  I just noticed that myself.  It is peculiar that RoboCopy uses GMT+0 and not what the user has set.  One nice thing to note is that the seconds do not change between time zones, therefore, the seconds can be used from what RoboCopy returns and use the values returned from `t` for the hour and minute.

Comment: well in any case, how can i incorporate the robocopy into the current script? perhaps when it actually outputs, the timezone will be switched back. i got your line to work standalone, but as for how to put it in the main script as the variables, i havent gotten yet. by the way, i'd like to say now thanks so far for all your help with this.

Comment: @Shiken  I have added the robocopy to my example. The example should now be fully functional. Just need to add in the rename command.

Comment: excellent, seems to be working perfectly after changing the /T:C to /T:W. the only remaining step would be changing it so that I can run this from the base "Processing" folder, to check each 01020304 etc subfolder rather than manually setting the folder each time.

Comment: @Shiken  I have updated my answer with a folder recursion script.

Comment: oh, quite the revision, i can't say i see exactly how it works yet, but i do know it DOES work, and i couldnt have done it without your help. thanks a ton! =)

Comment: @Shiken  Glad I could help.  Also I will break it down for you.  1. Hide Commands.  2. Isolate Variable Scope and Enable Abilities.  3. Create an empty folder for RoboCopy, so it does not spaz out.  4. Loop through the folders calling the `Process` function for each folder in the path.  5. The `Process` function takes 1 parameter which is the folder path.  6. Verify it has a Video folder.  7. Loop through each .avi file in the video folder.  8. Retrieve the Dates  9. Rename to the new file name.  10. `goto :eof` exits the function back to the caller.  `/?` and Technet are batch's best friends!